# Ordering by using Group_Concat proving tricky

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, group-concat

I'm somewhat new with php/mysql so I'm sure I'm missing something. This approach probably isn't the best either.

I have the following tables

Table: unit_members
Fields: id, unit_id, person_id, primary

Table: persons
Fields: id, name, rank_id

Table: ranks
Fields: id, name, rank

Table: units
Fields: id, name, rank

I'm trying to display each unit and the persons in each unit and have the persons sorted by rank which is an int field. It seems simple, but I'm unable to get the persons to be ordered by rank.rank.

Here's my query:

```
'SELECT unit_members.person_id, GROUP_CONCAT(persons.id) as personid, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name) as name, persons.rank_id, unit_members.unit_id, 
        units.id as unitid, units.name as unit, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT units.codename) as squad, ranks.id as rankid, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(ranks.rank) as rankrank 
FROM unit_members, ranks, persons, units
where persons.rank_id = ranks.id 
  and units.id = unit_members.unit_id 
  and persons.id = unit_members.person_id
group by units.codename
ORDER BY units.rank asc, ranks.rank asc';
```

It appears to me that the Order by here does not affect the Group_Concat, so my guess is I need to Order the Group_Concat somehow before it goes into an array. The array seems to order it by person id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the {} button to format code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have some misconceptions.

Your `ORDER BY` isn't going to affect the results of `GROUP_CONCAT()`. You can [change the order of results in a `GROUP_CONCAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) by specifying an order within the parens.

As it stands, your query is going to group by unit.codename, and within each unit.codename, the arbitrary results are going to be sorted first by units.rank, and then by ranks.rank.

A bigger problem: you keep talking about an array. There's no array here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give that a try later tonight. When I mention the array, I failed to mention what I was doing with the GROUP_CONCAT I am putting the following in a while: $name = $row['name']; $members_array = explode(",", $name); so I can easily put the contents of that GROUP_CONCAT into a list. Not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Actually I had a chance to try it earlier, but it didn't work. What did I do wrong? 

'code'
$roster_query = 'SELECT unit_members.person_id, GROUP_CONCAT(persons.id ORDER by ranks.rank desc) as personid, GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name ORDER by ranks.rank desc) as name,
... 
'code'

etc

Comment: Edit your question to include some sample data, and the output you expect. You'll need to supply a little sample data for each of the four tables.